# Display all of the outcomes in a list from one mod at at time

Tags: javascript, xml

This is the xml followed by the code I'm using to call it.  I would like all of the learning outcomes for a single jen_mod to display in a list.  You can see from my naming conventions, that a.) I am making sure that I can separate my code from the blackboard system, b.) I am old.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <jen_mod id = '1'>
        <jen_title> Introduction to the Course </jen_title>
                <jen_learning_outcome>Student will be able to  navigate the course, and contact the instructor.</jen_learning_outcome>
                <jen_learning_outcome>Student will be able to  explain the course requirements.</jen_learning_outcome>
                <jen_learning_outcome>Student will be able to complete a MyLab Demonstration.</jen_learning_outcome>
                <jen_learning_outcome>Student will be able to compile a basic lab report.</jen_learning_outcome>
                <jen_checklist>Read page: Start Here! </jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>Read page: About your Professor </jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>Discussion: Introduce yourself to the class. </jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>Survey: Introduce yourself to me!</jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>Read the Syllabus </jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>QUIZ: You will have 30 minutes to complete this quiz</jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>Try out a MYLAB to see how they work! </jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>Assignment: The basics of a MyLab Report</jen_checklist>
    </jen_mod>
    <jen_mod id = '2'>
        <jen_title> Evolution of Cognitive Psychology </jen_title>
                <jen_learning_outcome>Student will be able to describe the history of events related to cogntive psychology.</jen_learning_outcome>
                <jen_learning_outcome>Student will be able to explain the relationship between behavioral and cognitive psychology.</jen_learning_outcome>
                <jen_learning_outcome>Student will be able to name the  fields of cognitive study.</jen_learning_outcome>
                <jen_learning_outcome>Student will be able to </jen_learning_outcome>
                <jen_checklist>Reading: Introduction to Cognitive Psychology </jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>Video: The Wierdest Video about the History of Cognitive Psychology You'll See Today</jen_checklist>
                <jen_checklist>Quiz: Evolution of Cognitive Psychology</jen_checklist>
    </jen_mod>
    <jen_mod id = '3'>

...
```

//This is the last version of my working code.  I have tried several ways to iterate the learning outcomes but can't quite get the knack.

```
<div id="mod"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/


   loadmod(0);
```

//The blackboard system enters a zero here.  When I enter a value thinking I could call a particular mod it crashes

```
function loadmod(i) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this, i);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://blackboard.sc.edu/bbcswebdav/courses/DL-PSYC405-SANDBOX/HTMLOBJECTS/jen_modules_460.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml, i) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("jen_mod");
    document.getElementById("mod").innerHTML =
    "Module: " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("jen_title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Learning Outcome: " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("jen_learning_outcome")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
}
/*]]>*/</script>
```

Comment: How do you know it "crashes"? Is it giving you an error message? If so, what error message is it giving you?

Comment: I wish.  I get no feedback from the system.  All I know is that nothing appears on the screen.  If I set i=2 within my function I get the title and the first learning outcome from <jen_mod id =2>.

Comment: Nothing is printed in the developer console or the error log? Have you tried stepping through your code in the JavaScript debugger?

Comment: Which JavaScript debugger would you recommend?  I'm working inside a commercial platform, Blackboard.  I don't know how to incrementally output code into the platform and debug it step by step. Is there something like Firebug that I could use to debug outside of the system?

Comment: It's built into modern browsers. There are tutorials all over on how to step through code using the developer tools (Google is your friend here). Start by hitting F12.

Answer (score 0):

First-off, with XML you need one element as the root element of the entire document.

How you have it structured, there are multiple elements serving as the root element:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jen_mod id = '1'>...</jen_mod>
<jen_mod id = '2'>...</jen_mod>
```

You'll need to restructure so that there's one element in the root:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<my_mod_collection>
    <jen_mod id = '1'>...</jen_mod>
    <jen_mod id = '2'>...</jen_mod>
</my_mod_collection>
```

Comment: I have one root element <jen_course id = '405'>  </jen_course>.  Thank you.